# Sci-fi / dystopian book about a teenager/kid that gets stuck in VR but gets out and ends rather tragically

Tags: story-identification, novel

I vaguely remember a book that left me somewhat disgusted as I was quite young first reading it due to the graphic end, but now I'm left in shambles trying to figure out what the book was called.

It starts out with this kid going about his normal life and then he begins using a VR headset that is somehow fully attached to the users head leaving their bodies like a cooked vegetable whilst using it. Eventually playing the game he meets a girl that he gets into a relationship with, the game suddenly changes and they are unable to remove the headsets. If anyone were to forcibly remove the headset from the player, the player would end up dying as their mind would still be in the game? I barely remember much from it, other than in the end the main character ends up kicking his girlfriend in the head, killing her as she's still wearing the headset.

I'd like to find the title of the book if anyone has any idea of what it could be, thanks.

Comment: Welcome. Do you remember the year it was published (approx.), the language it was in, any cover-art?

Comment: A comment, because these are not answers to what it is or might be, but some things it is not. "Better Than Life" by Grant Naylor features the headset you can't remove forcibly, but not the other features (I don't recall the girl being killed as part of it). "Space Demons" (and at least one of the sequels) by Gillian Rubinstein features 'going into the game', but not via a headset. "The Dreamland Chronicles" (a trilogy) by Wm. Mark Simmons features life-pods, not headsets for the VR aspects.

Comment: Tad Williams's *Otherland* books has a teen boy (and several others) stuck in VR, and one dies in real life and can only live on in VR. However, there is no helmet-kicking incident that I can remember.